# The longitude and latitude coordinates on an sf/ggplot map are displaying with boxes rather than degree symbols

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, coordinates, r-sf

[map with incorrect degree symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rexMO.png)

I am creating a geographical map of Germany in R with gggplot2 and sf for the first time which takes geographic data from a shape file and numerical data from a csv. I created a dataframe which combines the two and am using that new df for my plot. Normally, coordinates use a degree symbol. For example, 54 degrees north is written as 50°N. However, with my current code, it looks like 54[]N,where [] represents a box.

```
            shp_file <- st_read("GIS/NUTS_RG_01M_2010_3035.shp") 

            de_shp_file <- themap %>%
              filter(shp_file$CNTR_CODE == "DE")

            de_data <- read.csv("K....csv", sep=";")

            de_df <- merge(de_shp_file, de_data, by = "NUTS_ID", rm.na=FALSE)

            de_df %>%
              filter(period == "1949 - 1978") %>%
                 ggplot(aes(fill = var1)) + geom_sf() + labs(title = "my title")
```

I have the following packages active in my library:

```
[1] "sqldf"        "RSQLite"      "gsubfn"       "proto"        "MASS"[6] "officer"      "officedown"   "flextable"    "remotes"      "sm"[11] "reshape2"     "knitr"        "leaflet"      "tmaptools"    "tmap"[16] "sf"         "RColorBrewer" "quantreg"     "SparseM"      "ggspectra"[21] "photobiology" "fable"        "feasts"       "fabletools"   "tsibbledata"[26] "tsibble"      "fpp3"         "writexl"      "psych"        "lubridate"[31] "forcats"      "stringr"      "dplyr"        "purrr"        "readr"[36] "tidyr"        "tibble"       "ggplot2"      "tidyverse"    "readxl"[41] "stats"        "graphics"     "grDevices"    "utils"        "datasets"[46] "methods"      "base"
```

I was expecting the degree symbol to show up as shown here: [map with correct degree symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9qOi.png)

Comment: This box means that the default font you are using does not have a glyph defined for the degree symbol, and it's not really got anything to do with the packages you have loaded. Try adding `+ theme(axis.text = element_text(family = 'serif'))` to your plot, as you may have the degree symbol in your default serif font.

Comment: Windows & RStudio? What's your graphics device (*Tools > Global Options > General > Graphics*) ? If it's still *default / Windows*,  try if switching to *Cairo* or *AGG* makes a difference. I see the same behaviour but only when rendering through `reprex`, apparently this makes knitr to use different settings. When using AGG or Cairo, degree symbol in RStudio plots in present.

Comment: @margusl - thanks - changing to Cairo solved the problem!